# HttpResponseMessage asp.net : How to integrate basic authentication

Tags: asp.net, basic-authentication, httpresponsemessage

How do I implement a basic authentication filter into a working web api client written in asp.net `HttpResponseMessage`.

How do I check the authentication (user:pass or 64Base Key) and if failed pass unauthorised message.

This is my current code and it work:

```
    public HttpResponseMessage WebAPiPost([FromBody]byte[] incomingData)
    { 

        string rawData = getRawPostData().Result;
        var responseMessage= (HttpResponseMessage)null;

        responseMessage =  new HttpResponseMessage()
        {Content = new StringContent(SQLFunctions.SQLStoredProcedureJson("StoredProcedureName", rawData, true), System.Text.Encoding.UTF8, "application/json")};
        return responseMessage;
    }
```

Comment: Check the following documentation https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/security/authentication-filters

Comment: Is there a simple way to integrate this?

Comment: What do you mean by simple? It is all explained in the documentation. Take some to review it and then implement it.

Comment: I thought it can be done it few lines. eventually I use [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/security/basic-authentication) and succeeded. Thanks for the direction.